# Pushwoosh - no subscribers are added in android

Tags: android, pushwoosh, remoteapi

I am trying to add new subscriber with pushwoosh remote api services.

**RegisterDevice**

```
POST https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice
{
    "request": {
        "application": "XXXX-XXXX",    // THE PROJECT ID ON PUSHWOOSH
        "push_token": "APA........",   // GOOGLE DEVICE REGISTRATION KEY
        "language": "en",
        "hwid": "YYYYYYYYY",           //UUID
        "device_type": 3               //ANDROID
    }
}
// RESULT 200 - OK
```

My app works perfectly fine.

when i check my pushwoosh control panel i see subscribers
but the Android platform shows no subscribers.

I cross checked the project id , server key... and everything fine.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the server response. It should be 200 and status code is "ok".

Sometimes when the Cloud is super busy it might take a minute or two for the devices to appear.

Comment: the server result is 200.
general number of subscribers increased.
specific project subscribers is still 0.

Comment: Can you provide an app code or a push token you are sending? This way I can check with backend team what goes with your request.

Comment: did you found something?

Comment: Could you provide full request? I suspect something wrong with UUID (wrong format?).

Comment: POST https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/registerDevice
{
    "request": {
        "application": "8A2BB-6FB4C",
        "push_token": "xxxxx",
        "language": "en",
        "hwid": "39FFF03812858AD5",
        "device_type": 3
    }
}

Comment: I can see you have a subscriber now. However I see the error when you tried to send push: MismatchSenderId.
Make sure your Google Project Id matches your Server key you enter in the Control Panel!

Comment: yes, it's match i am using the server key and getting the error.

Comment: This error comes from Google and it means that Project ID you specified in the app does not match the server key you entered in Pushwoosh Control panel. There's nothing I can do. You could try following the guides precisely.
Try this video as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdvqJTLgq6M